# Partition BigQuery materialized view on aggregated column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partition, materialized-views

I have a table **logs** with these columns:

*timestamp sessionID elementID value*

The **logs** table is partitioned on the *timestamp* column.

I create a materialized view out of it:

```
create materialized view X
partition by date(new_timestamp)
as
select min(timestamp) as new_timestamp, sessionID, elementID, sum(value) as sumvalue 
from logs 
group by sessionID, elementID
```

I am getting an error "Partitioning column of the materialized view must either match partitioning column or pseudo-column of the base table, or be a TIMESTAMP_TRUNC over it."

BigQuery doc says the only way to partition the materialized view is to use exactly the same partition column of the main table, even the min() operator on the column is not accepted. Do you know how I could achieve the result I want despite this limitation?

Comment: did you try `partition by TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(new_timestamp, DAY)`? If you want to have the date value only (not the hour, minutes, seconds,...) it's equivalent to cast it into Date.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Timestamp_trunc also does now work because new_timestamp is not the partition column of the mother table. The partition column that I should use to partition the materialized view is timestamp, but I can't use it directly for my usecase. I need the min over all the timestamps of each group.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I want to use a different (calculated) column in MV compared to the base table partition column.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

A fresh look on your question gave me a simple answer: Use `timestamp` directly!

Indeed, you will store in the materialized view only the `min(timestamp)`. So, the partitioning/sharding of your data will be done by timestamp, min or max, it's not the purpose!

Comment: I wish it would work, but I can't partition on timestamp if I don't expose the timestamp field directly in the select statement. I can't expose it because I would have to aggregate on it too, and that would break the logic of the table.

Comment: Agree.... Anyway, are you sure of your query? How to get the min timestamp if you group by timestamp? In this case min(timestamp) always = to timestamp, no?

Comment: Thanks for the message, I added it there by mistake. The grouping should be done just on sessionID and elementID, I modified the query in the original message :) Unfortunately I still haven't found a solution to the problem...

Comment: I tried your problem and to solved it in different way: subquery, join,... all these features are, for now, deactivated from Materialized view. So, I think that you can't achieve this for now... maybe in 6 months or so...

Comment: Thanks, hopefully even sooner than that :)

Comment: Hi Guillaume, 1 year later, do you know if there is a way to fix that?